# cc line populated with dataextension values using ampscript lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I need my CC line to pull in the values stored in a DE. Each cc line will contain two email addresses - the emails must be semicolon separated in order for MC to recognize as 2 separate emails.

I've got two questions:

1. Do I do this using the lookup function? Something like `%%[ SET @cc = LOOKUP(@SendingDE, "@cc", "EmailAddress", EmailAddress) ]%%`
2. I need to consider if one of the email addresses is blank as I don't want the semicolon to display if there is no second email address.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... No. If you're trying to cc other inboxes with your content, you can't do this with Marketing Cloud in anything like the way I suspect you're imagining. You can pay for CC functionality, if you want to copy the email to a specified inbox for compliance and audit type reasons, but arbitrary cc'ing of other email addresses... No.